# Noun Phrase Extraction Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, nlp

What is the interpretation of the RE given below

```
r'KT: {(<JJ>* <NN.*>+ <IN>)? <JJ>* <NN.*>+}'
```

I don't know what KT is but JJ is adjective, NN is noun and IN is preposition.

EDIT: reposting the link
http://bdewilde.github.io/blog/2014/09/23/intro-to-automatic-keyphrase-extraction/

Comment: Why don't you try it on some text and see the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're working with the [Penn part-of-speech tags](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/amalgam/tagsets/upenn.html),

`<NN.*>+` matches at least one of

- `NN`: Noun, singular or mass
- `NNS`: Noun, plural
- `NNP`: Proper noun, singular
- `NNPS`: Proper noun, plural

`<JJ>` matches at least zero adjectives (not comparative or superlative), so that's optional.

The `<JJ>* <NN.*>+` part of your RegEx thus matches at least one noun. That noun can be preceded by any number of adjectives. For example:

- `cats`
- `brown cats`
- `cute brown cats`

`(<JJ>* <NN.*>+ <IN>)?` means that the above can be preceded by another noun phrase and a preposition (`IN`), such as

- `green eyes of cute brown cats`

`KT` is not a part-of-speech tag. The code you've referenced works with [NLTK's RegexpParser](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.chunk.html#nltk.chunk.regexp.RegexpParser), where grammars are (roughly) defined as `Label: {rules}`. So `KT` is really just a label that each identified noun phrase will take; you might as well name it `NP` or `NounPhrase`.